# Create an XML File using XmlSerializer with elements and attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlserializer

First of all, I appreciate your time helping me out. I am  new to C# and while I can work out most things, there are areas that I really struggle.

I am capturing SNMP traps and want to save them into an XML file. I have the following class:

```
   Public class data
    {
         public string id;
         public string name;
         public string OIDvalue;
    }
```

I want to create an XML File similar to the following which will have variable number of id and oid.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <devices>
        <device id="ID23213">
            <oids>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424" value="345"></oid>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424.244.22" value="test"></oid>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424.244.23" value="test1"></oid>
            </oids>
        </device>
        <device id="ID111">
            <oids>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424" value="38382"></oid>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424.244.22" value="twehjwe98"></oid>
                <oid name="10.22.1213.212.2424.244.23" value="uhu889"></oid>
                <oid name="textBased.Reference.Pointer" value="88889"></oid>
                <oid name="textBased.Reference.Pointer.10.111" value="0909"></oid>
            </oids>
        </device>
    </devices>
</data>
```

I am using the following code to create the XML File

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    xs.Serialize(fs, snmp);
}
```

I have done a fair bit of research and getting confused with the different options available and so far none have worked. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy one.
Lets go with the other way round.

If you the XML structure, then generate C# file for your xml, using xsd.exe(you can google how to generate)

Then its just writing it to the XML file using your C# class.